# て-form+quotation

Tags: grammar, て-form

As in:

> 足の悪い鶴ははずかしそうにふりかえっ**て**、「さっきね、何かないかと思って沼のなかを探していたのさ。」

What is the て-form of the verb doing here? Does it have to do with a dropped verb, the placement of the quotation, or is it something else entirely?

Comment: This is just the verb ふりかえる.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The verb that is supposed to be paired with ふりかえる is omitted.

> 足の悪い鶴ははずかしそうにふりかえって、「さっきね、何かないかと思って沼のなかを探していたのさ。」（と**言った**。）

> 足の悪い鶴ははずかしそうにふりかえって、（こう**言った**。）「さっきね、何かないかと思って沼のなかを探していたのさ。」

I guess it is supposed to be a storytelling technique or something. I wouldn’t say it’s very common.